# shell script + constant spaces between the IP to the aliases name

Tags: ksh

from my ksh script

.

```
echo $IP1  $ALIAS1 >> /etc/hosts
echo $IP2  $ALAIS2 >> /etc/hosts
echo $IP3  $ALIAS3 >> /etc/hosts
```

I get the hosts file as the following

```
10.10.10.10 node1_star
10.10.10.100    node_from_some_where
10.10.1.1              Node_HP_MACHINE
```

what the simple way to create the following hosts file view 
in order to get constant spaces between the IP to the aliases name
as the follwoing:

(it could be by printf or by echo manipulation)

```
10.10.10.10        node1_star
10.10.10.100       node_from_some_where
10.10.1.1          Node_HP_MACHINE
```

Comment: its strange, that you mentioned printf and echo, but you don't know how to do it? Check the man page if you don't know what a command does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` is a powerful function that can do exactely what you want.

```
printf "%-20s %s\n" "$IP1" "$ALIAS1" >> /etc/hosts
```